# Post from android to web then get result

Tags: android

***I need your help***
 please i'm trying to build and apps that i can from it to post the number of a car in the web,  then get the result to know if i have a speed ticket or no.
But i have a problem in posting the number from the apps into the text box that are included in this website.
please can you tell me how can i do it
this is the web
http://apps.isf.gov.lb/speedticket/speedticket_ar.php/
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal should not be to post it in the text box, but rather post to the form's target URL the value for the variable named in the text box using an HTTP_POST call.